# Implementation Add Connection of Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, database-connection

I want to create Connect To DataBase form(Something like Visual Studio 2012 Add Connection
I find this code to find Connected server

```
  private void FillServerComboBox()
    {
            DataTable ServersTable = new DataTable();
            SqlDataSourceEnumerator servers = SqlDataSourceEnumerator.Instance;
            ServersTable = servers.GetDataSources();

            object[] obj = new object[ServersTable.Rows.Count];
            for (int i = 0; i < ServersTable.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                obj[i] = string.Format("{0}\\{1}", ServersTable.Rows[i]["ServerName"].ToString(), ServersTable.Rows[i]["InstanceName"].ToString());
            }
            serversComboBox.DataSource = obj;         
    }
```

And I find "Master.dbo.sp_Databases" procedure to list databases on remote server. But I do not have permission on MasterTable. How does "Add Connection Form" work on Visual Studio?
But it does not work. Please guide me on that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an asnwer

```
      SqlConnection _SqlConnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
        _SqlConnection.Open();
        DataTable dt1 =   _SqlConnection.GetSchema("Tables");
```

and

```
      SqlConnection _SqlConnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
        _SqlConnection.Open();
        DataTable dt1 =   _SqlConnection.GetSchema("DataBases");
```